# CAT6 cable AWG23 seems too thick for plugs

Tags: ethernet, cabling, cable, layer1

I have 500 feet of what is described as Cat6 Solid STP Copper Bulk Cable (White)

Here are the full specs

- CAT6 STP  8-Conductor, Bulk, PVC Jacket, (FTP) Shiedled AWG23,
  Solid-Bare Copper,(UL/ETL)
- High-Performance Data Communications Cable for noisy Environment
  Suitable for 550MHz High-Speed Data Applications, Gigabit Ethernet,
  Fast Ethernet and 155Mbps TP-PMD/CDDI
- Designed for Indoor Installations (CMR) Riser
- Category-6 Shielded Twisted Pair (STP) Cable
- 4-Pair – Easily Identified Color-Striped Pairs
- 23 AWG Solid Bare Copper Conductors
- Excellent Attenuation and Crosstalk Characteristics
- Exceeds EIA/TIA 568 B.2-1
- UL/cUL or ETL Listed
- Sequential Length Markings on Jacket

*Fantastic*

I bought 23 AWG CAT6 plugs with the sled and tray and it just seems as though there is physically not enough room for all the wires to fit. I've been at it for a couple hours and I have not crimped a single cable successfully.I can't get them in to fit.

I've done this with CAT5 and 5E countless times. I've never had this issue before.

Is this a thing known to happen? I know product recommendations are not allowed but is there a spec of plug I should be looking for.

For reference, here is a [link](http://cables4sure.com/cat6-solid-stp-bulk-cables/500ft-cat6-solid-stp-copper-bulk-cable-white.html) to the cable I purchased:

PS: If this doesn't belong here, downvote to oblivion.
I'll delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, Category-6 cable is *not* shielded cable, it is specifically UTP (*Unshielded* Twisted-Pair) cable. All cable categories are defined by ANSI/TIA/EIA, and they are all for UTP. The ISO/IEC defines cable classes (not categories), some of which are for shielded cable, but you must have the corresponding shielded connectors, and you must have an electrically continuous shield from device to device that is grounded, at least, on both ends, otherwise the shielded cable will perform worse than UTP, and it is probably unsuitable for use. Shielding that isn't properly grounded actually exacerbates the problems it is meant to correct.

Next, solid-core cable is used for horizontal cable (the cable in the walls) because it is fragile, and it should not be moved very often, if at all. In fact, your description claims it is riser cable, not suitable for connecting with crimped plugs. The UTP plugs for patch cords are designed for stranded cable, and the punch down terminations for solid-core cable are on the wall plates and patch panels.

For your patch cords (what you crimp), you use stranded cable because it is less fragile, although it offers less performance, but the cabling specifications allow you up to 90 meters of solid-core, horizontal cable, and a combined 10 meters of stranded cable (five meters on each end).

---

I do not mean any disrespect, but because you don't know these things, you really are not qualified to install Category-6 cable. Even experienced cable installers can have trouble getting a Category-6 installation to pass the required Category-6 test suite, and I doubt you have the proper (read very expensive) tester or experience to certify a Category-6 installation.

Comment: No disrespect taken. I'm just doing this in my house and basically bought the wrong thing due lack of knowledge. Thanks for the good info.